# Differentiating a trapezoid from squares and rectangles

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to develop an algorithm to detect a trapezoidal shape. I am trying to figure out a way to detect the angle inverted of the trapezoid to differentiate between squares and trapezoids.

I simply loop through the contours, and try to distinguish the trapezoid by other features, as I am not really sure how I could check that the lines are inverse on the trapezoid. Any Ideas?

Here is an example of what I am tracking:
[image]

This is what I came up with so far:

```
for cnt in contourList:
        hull = cv2.convexHull(cnt)
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
        area = h * w * 1.0
        originalArea = cv2.contourArea(hull)

        #skip if not minimum area
        if(originalArea < 200 ):
            continue #too small!

        kMinTargetWidth = 20
        kMaxTargetWidth = 300
        kMinTargetHeight = 6
        kMaxTargetHeight = 60
        if(w < kMinTargetWidth or w  > kMaxTargetWidth):
            continue
        if(h < kMinTargetHeight or h > kMaxTargetHeight):
            continue


        #Ratio of width to height
        #ratio should be 1 or greater
        #target is 43 cm tall, 100 cm wide
        ratio = float(w) / float(h)
        if(ratio < 1.3):
            continue #skip

        kMinFullness = .50
        kMaxFullness = .95
        fullness = originalArea / area
        if(fullness < kMinFullness or fullness > kMaxFullness):
            continue

        if(cv2.isContourConvex(cnt) == True):
            continue
```

My hope was that the concave nature of these trapezoid objects would be able to be differentiated versus the rectangles/squares. I am now thinking I should check the side angle somehow as well.

Or take the convex hull and find the corner points. But I feel like OpenCV has something like this built in already? Basically I am asking what I am missing!

Comment: See cv2.approxPolyDP() at https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga0012a5fdaea70b8a9970165d98722b4c and https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-detect-polygons-in-an-image-using-opencv/. Find the contours, approximate at quadrilaterals. Get the vertices. Draw lines. Check angles and slopes. A trapezoid is a quadrilateral with only one pair of parallel sides. A rectangle will have 90 deg angles and two pair of parallel sides.

Comment: In your example picture, which objects are trapezoids and which are not? (if you could depict them it would help, as well as adding more examples)

Answer (score 0):

If you define `contourList` and `cv2`, and identify the packages you import, then my suggestions could be more directed.

Simply working with a trapezoid, I'd suggest using the trapezoid feature: one set of opposite lines are parallel and the other set are not.  This requires knowing the slopes of the four lines.  If you don't know those slopes directly, but you know the vertices, then you could calculate the four slopes.

Essentially, using the definition of a trapezoid is robust, and there are multiple ways you could determine parallel and non-parallel.